# Laravel 5 TokenMismatch on Backbone.js destroy method, with _token set

Tags: backbone.js, laravel-5.1

I am trying to delete a model via:

```
var FeaturedUsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click .remove-featured-user" : "removeFeaturedUser"
    },
    template : _.template(FeaturedUsersTemplate),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template({ featuredUsers:  App.featuredUsers.toJSON() })); 
        return this;
    },
    removeFeaturedUser: function(event) {
        userToRemove = this.collection.get(event.target.id);
        userToRemove.set("_token", $('input[name="_token"]').val());
        userToRemove.destroy({
            wait: true,
            /*
             *headers: {
             *    _token : $('input[name="_token"]').val()
             *},  
             *async: false,
             */
            url: '/api/admin/versions/' + App.config.get("class_id") + '/featured_users',
        });


    }
});
```

I keep getting a ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException'.

This same view have a model.save() that works with the same token. I have a feeling the destroy method is ignoring the token in the DELETE request. Any tips?

Here is backbone.js's destroy method:

```
destroy: function(options) {
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;
  var wait = options.wait;

  var destroy = function() {
    model.stopListening();
    model.trigger('destroy', model, model.collection, options);
  };

  options.success = function(resp) {
    if (wait) destroy();
    if (success) success.call(options.context, model, resp, options);
    if (!model.isNew()) model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
  };

  var xhr = false;
  if (this.isNew()) {
    _.defer(options.success);
  } else {
    wrapError(this, options);
    xhr = this.sync('delete', this, options);
  }
  if (!wait) destroy();
  return xhr;
},
```

Comment: show all contents of view and destroy method body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this globally fixed my problem:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```